# User certificate removal on Android

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, android-keystore

I'm currently developing an application which consists on an Android client for SCEP protocol. This protocol provides an automatic method of certificate enrollment and renewal for mobile devices into a PKI.

Due to that, I'm facing with the problem that with the Android version I'm using (4.2) I'm not able to remove user certificates to execute renewal process.

I don't mind if it can be done silently or not, I just want to know if user-certificates removal from Android KeyStore can be done programatically on a non-rooted Android device.

Thanks in advance.